# Access 2010 forms: direct entry of foreign key into text box

Tags: forms, microsoft-access-2010

In a form I am creating for an MS Access 2010 database, one of the fields represents a foreign key. I would like this field to be displayed as a text box, rather than as a combo or list box as is usual for foreign keys (the main reason being that the lists would become far too long and uncomfortable to use, and I would rather have users enter the key directly). However, I cannot get it to work so that I can directly enter a foreign key in that text box. Instead of taking the foreign key I entered and following the reference to the existing tuple in the other relation, Access always seems to try and create a *new* tuple in the other relation, which of course fails since a tuple with an identical key already exists (i.e., the one I tried to reference).

To put it more practically, the problem I am having is this: I have a row with ID 100 in table **A**. I want to create a new row in table **B**, with a foreign key of 100 used to refer to that row in table **A**. The table relation is correctly set up in Access. If I edit table **B** in spreadsheet view, I can directly enter the foreign key of 100, and everything works as I want it to. However, if I do the same thing on the form Access complains about a duplicate key, because instead of simply storing the foreign key of 100 in table **B**, it also tries to create an entirely *new* row with the now duplicate ID of 100 in table **A**. I hope this is more or less understandable.

I tried declaring the foreign key field in table B as a combo lookup field, but unless I also change the field on the form from a text to a combo box, the problem persists. Googling also led me to try declaring the following as the data source for the foreign key text box on the form:

```
=DlookUp("[ID]", "[TableA]", "[ID]=" & Forms![Form2]![txtID1])
```

but I only ever get a syntax error out of this. Also, the Access help files only cover the *DlookUp* function up to version 2007—is it possible that this function is no longer available in Access 2010?

How can I allow users to enter a foreign key directly into a text field on a form, without Access trying to create a new row in the referenced table? Would the data source code above solve my problem if I could get it to work?

Comment: It sounds to me that your record source for the form is pointing to table A when it should be using Table B

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just went to check, but the record source of the form is correctly set to relation B.

Comment: Which table are you trying to add data to?  Is it table A or table B?

Comment: Table B. I would like the new tuple in B to reference an existing tuple in A via a foreign key. As stated in the question, this works if I enter the foreign key directly in B's table view, but not if I enter it into the same field using a text box on a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  I understand what you are trying to do now.  There are two options available to you depending on what you want to do.

Option 1:  I think this is the more elegant solution.  Create a query that joins the two tables together.  If allowed, the new query will be editable and you can pull out the information you seek in Table A and place directly into the textbox.  See this website to determine why your new query may be read only.  http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html

Option 2:  Continue to use the combo box on the form and create a picture that will mask the down arrow of the combo box.

Comment: Option 1 is a good workaround. I still think it should be possible to make the form's textbox behave like the cell in spreadsheet view, but I can use this method to accomodate end-users. Thank you!